# I need code behind version of Image source binding

Tags: xaml

code behind.

```
Class MainWindow 

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

    Dim myBinding As New Binding
    With myBinding
        .Source = Image1.Source
        .Mode = BindingMode.Default
        .UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
    End With
End Sub

End Class
```

So, why **myBinding** is not working in code behind?

Comment: So...c# or VB.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have the Binding updated when its source property changes, you need to specify a Path:

```
Dim myBinding As New Binding
With myBinding
    .Source = Image1
    .Path = new PropertyPath("Source")
End With
```

---

Besides that, setting `BindingMode.Default` and `UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` is pointless. It has no effect on this Binding.